# Hide / toggle specific column jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table of tables in HTML. And what I want to do is toggle specific columns.
The goal is that the user can select which columns to display.

This is my table (simplified):

```
  <table id="mainview" class="table table-striped table-bordered">
    <th>Column1</th>
    <th>Column2</th>
    <th>Column3</th>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <th>One</th>
          <th>Two</th>
          <th>Three</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>text</td>
           <td>text</td>
           <td>text</td>
         </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <th>One</th>
          <th>Two</th>
          <th>Three</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>text</td>
           <td>text</td>
           <td>text</td>
         </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
      <td>
        <table class="table table-bordered">
        <tr>
          <th>One</th>
          <th>Two</th>
          <th>Three</th>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>text</td>
           <td>text</td>
           <td>text</td>
         </tr>
        </table>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
```

I have this input for the moment to choose which column to toggle:

```
<input id="number" value="2">
<button id="toggle">Toggle</button>`
```

And this is my script:

```
function fire() {
    var v = $('#number').val() || 0;
    $('#mainview tr').closest(':nth-child('+v+')').toggle();
}
$('#toggle').click(fire);
```

My problem is, when I want to toggle a columns, it also affect all the nth columns of each secondary table. How can I only select the parent columns?

Comment: Give it a specific name to the table and use that as the ID instead of #mainview.

Comment: I don't see how this is going to solve the problem. I tried it and it didn'nt work out for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```js
$('#toggle').on('click', function(){

 var v = $('#number').val() || 0;
 $('#mainview > tbody > tr > th:nth-child('+v+')').toggle();
 $('#mainview > tbody > tr > td:nth-child('+v+')').toggle();
});
```

And here is the output:

[image]

Comment: Works fine, but is there a way I can also hide the header of the column and not only the sub table ?

Comment: Yes, you can. I just updated my answer. Follow this code.

Comment: Yes it will hide the th of the childs but still won't hide the th contqining the hidden table row

Comment: Do you want this output, which I just updated in my answer?